# Ef core search on child , order on parent

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two model Parent and Child and I want to retrieve all Distinct parent that has unitid = 5 and order by family

```
 public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Parent parent { get; set; }
}
```

parent table has 500000 record and child table has 2000000 record . I use SelectMany And Distinct but it take 8s to retrieve records

```
var parents= Context.Set<Parent>()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Children.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                                (u, r) => new { 
                                          Parent = u, 
                                          Child = r })
                    .Where(x=>x.Child.UnitId == 5)
                    .Select(m => new Parent{ 
                                      Id = m.Parent.Id, 
                                      Family= m.Parent.Family
                                 })
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(x=>x.Family)
                    .Take(30).Skip(0).ToList();
```

Tranlate to :

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Family] FROM (
SELECT  distinct [a].[Id],  [a].[Family]
FROM [Parent]  AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Children] AS [r] ON [a].[Id] = [r].[ParentId]
WHERE  ([r].[unitid] = 5) AS [t] ORDER BY [t].[family] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH next 30 ROWS ONLY
```

Or

```
var parents = Context.Set<Children>()
                     .Include(x=>x.Parent)
                     .Where(x=>x.UnitId ==5)
                     .Select(m => new Parent{ 
                                      Id = m.ParentId , 
                                      Family = m.Parent.Family})
                     .Distinct()
                     .OrderBy(x=>x.Family)
                     .Take(30).Skip(0).ToList();
```

Translatr to :

```
SELECT [t0].[Id],[t0].[Family] FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [t].[Id], [t].[Family]
FROM [Children] AS [r]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [a].[Id] , [a].[Family]
    FROM [Parent] AS [a]
) AS [t] ON [r].[ParentId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE ([r].[UnitId] = 5)  AS [t0] ORDER BY [t0].[Family] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH next 30 ROWS ONLY
```

1 . When use order by id it is very fast

2 . when use order by family and take,skip it is slow

3 . family is indexed

4 . Ef Core 3.1

Which solution is Correct or better ?

Comment: first if u use `EFCore < 3.0`, it has a weird feature called ***client-side query auto-evaluation***, so be sure that the data is not unintentionally pulled all to the client and processed on the client by looking in the `Output` window to see if there is any ***Warning*** about that auto-evaluation. Second, you can try the generated query directly to see if u can actually optimize it by writing raw query. If it's not then it's limited by your database (not by LINQ). And here in this case, I doubt that the `Family` is not indexed, ordering on that column will be extremely slow. Try indexing it

Comment: family in indexed and EfCore 3.1 , in sql server when I wrote left join from child to parent result is fast . but in EF I can't left join from child to parent . it translate to inner join

Comment: there is one `Distinct` in your query, I'm afraid that you do not include that in your left-join query (maybe just for testing the speed). If the composite columns to be distinct are in one table, we can easily apply an index on that, but here they are on 2 tables. I can see that it will result in a fairly complicated query. If possible you should try sharing that query for others to have a look at.

Comment: `SelectMany` will use inner-join. To explicitly use left-join, you may have to use `GroupJoin`. But still we need to find out if it's actually slowed by inner-join or not. I mean it should be fair when writing the queries between slow & fast versions.

Comment: Distinct is for prevent duplicate parent row .  Yes when I remove distinct result is fast but duplicated record from parent. There is no index in distinct column .

Comment: they are clearly from the parent in the first query, but not in the second query. Actually it depends on how the database processes the query because actually the 2 projected columns are from a temp result (not from a table directly as in a simple `select ... from`). So it's hard to say. I think it's still hard to explain why `Id ordering` is fast whereas `Family ordering` is slow although I know `int indexing` is much faster.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty translate it to left join . I will send query in post ...

Comment: OK, so that means the generated inner-join (you said before) was from the second query? This comes a bit challenging because you should test the 2 queries for every possible made adjustment.

Comment: talking about the difference between `Id ordering` & `Family ordering`, although we know that `int indexing` is faster than `string indexing` but I'm not sure about how different it is. You can test that out by running a query ordering on each of them in a simple table select query. Once you find out that difference is close enough to `8s`, you have no choice by try improving the query in the other parts, such as the `Distinct`, for that try indexing the pair of columns `Id` & `Family` in the parent table to see if it's run faster. Note indexing 2 columns is different from indexing each one

Answer (score 0):

Check these two queries for performance:

```cs
var parents = 
    from p in Context.Set<Parent>()
    where p.Children.Any(c => c.UnitId == 5)
    orderby p.Family
    select p;

parents = parents
    .Take(30)
    .Skip(0)
    .ToList();
```

And another one:

```cs
var parentIds = 
    from c in Context.Set<Child>()
    where c.UnitId == 5
    select c.ParentId

var parents = 
    from p in Context.Set<Parent>()
    join id in parentIds.Distinct() on p.Id equals id
    orderby p.Family
    select p;

parents = parents
    .Take(30)
    .Skip(0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: these queries are definitely simpler than the query logic written by the OP, however it's still unsure if it can perform considerably better. Let's just wait for the OP's response :)

Comment: I test two query but problem not fixed . family column is in persian language is it important for search and order ?

Comment: Original question is not about ordering in persian language. But yes it is a problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#column-collation

Comment: @DavoodMir that's what I doubted :) really the first generated query posted in your question can hardly be made simpler. Although the LINQ queries in this answer look simpler but the generated queries may not :). BTW, have you tried my suggestion about indexing the pair of `Id` & `Family`? From the first generated query you posted, I'm pretty sure that it should improve the performance considerably.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv your answer in this post improved performance , https://stackoverflow.com/a/66152338/3332302