# EF core left join from child to parent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can we left join from child to parent ?

```
 var query = Child.Join(Context.Set<Parent>(), r => r.ParentId, u => u.Id,
            (r, u) => new
            {
                Parent= u,
                Child= r
            });
```

This is translate to inner-join , but I want left join

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to do that with LINQ Query syntax:

```cs
var query =
    from c in Context.Set<Child>() 
    join p in Context.Set<Parent>() on c.ParentId equals p.Id into gj
    from p in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        Parent = p,
        Child = c
    };
```